# how do i pass pointer ref to native method in JNI

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface, jna

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to open the port by calling Native method from ITLSSPProc.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521284/unable-to-open-the-port-by-calling-native-method-from-itlsspproc-dll)

I am calling functions of `ITLSSPProc.dll` by using JNI which has function `OpenSSPComPort(Pointer param);`

This pointer ref points to *baudrate* and
*portnumber* in memory here is the code i have tried but not able to
open the port.

```
public class Main {
    public interface ITLSSPProc extends Library {
        ITLSSPProc INSTANCE = (ITLSSPProc) 
            Native.loadLibrary((Platform.isWindows() 
                                    ? "ITLSSPProc" 
                                    : "simpleDLLWindowsPort"), 
                                ITLSSPProc.class);

        int OpenSSPComPort(Pointer param); 
        int CloseSSPComPort(Pointer param);                            
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        ITLSSPProc sdll = ITLSSPProc.INSTANCE;
        Memory intMem = new Memory(10);  // allocating space
        intMem.setLong(0,9600);
        intMem.setString(1,"com7");

        Pointer intPointer = intMem.getPointer(0);

        if(sdll.OpenSSPComPort(intMem)==1)
        {
            System.out.println("connected");
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have also gone through problem, i think you are not getting exact signature for native method, so gives exception when you are trying to initialize native method from ITLSSPProc.dll file.

Comment: `Memory` is equivalent to `Pointer`.  You'd be better off defining a `Structure` to hold your structured data.  Your issue here is probably with writing a 64-bit value at offset zero of your memory, followed by writing the bytes of a string to offset one of your memory.

Comment: so where i am going wrong can we define the struct in java and pass its pointer to method